# Kafkajs - How to handle the spam of error logs

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

Currently I am using Kafka.js version 2.2.4 in my node applications and since day 1, kafka.js keeps spamming errors logs. Like 2 days per week. Hundreds of error logs. These are examples of the logs.

```
Connection error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established\\\",\\\"broker\\\"
```

- 

```
Connection.logError (/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connection.js:111:7)\",\"extractedFields\":{\"message\":\"at Connection.logError (/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connection.js:111:7)\"}},
```

```
\\\"logger\\\":\\\"kafkajs\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"[Runner] The group is rebalancing, re-joining\\\",\\\"groupId\\\":\\\"merchant-portal-group-mp-prod\\\",\\\"memberId\\\":\\\"kafkajs-ccd39e17-085f-43de-a2d3-fc9ae1bf8d4a\\\",\\\"error\\\":\\\"This is not the correct coordinator for this group\\\"}\"}}]}"
```

Couple of time the service crashed or the messages were queued up for hours and hours and not consumed. But 99% of the time it's functioning correctly. The only annoying part is those error logs that sometimes it starts and goes on for hours.

Anyone experienced such cases? I just want to understand if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: TLS errors are related to network or certs, so check those. Otherwise Rebalancing is a normal operation. It'll automatically happen if your consumer is waiting too long to process data, so we need more details

Comment: The app continues to work fine but spams a lot of logs related to TLS connection. What kind of network issues can be there if the app is functioning normally?